# background image with horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, styles

I have a background image in bottom right of the page.

when i compress the browser width, the background image is cropped at the left side. Means i can't browse the background image with the horizontal scroll bar.

I have below background properties.

background-image:url('Image.png');
  background-size: 564px 282px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

Please let me know, what im missing here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use background-size:100%;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No horizontal scrolling for images:**

You need to add `background-size` css attribute to either `contain`, `fit` or `100%`.
This will make your image to appear without horizontal scrolling.

**For horizontal scrolling for images:**

If you want scrolling, then you have to give a min-width and that width should be same as the background image width.

Comment: scrolling is not possible for an image in bottom left or bottom right?

Comment: This will stop scrolling. If you want scrolling, then you have to give a min-width and that width should be same as the image width. - @John

Answer (score 1):

try css3 animation?

```
@-webkit-keyframes move{
from {background-position: bottom right;}
to {background-position: bottom left;}
}

div{
-webkit-animation:move 5s;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

and also paste your current code here